# PFQueryTableViewController Ignoring Pagination Setting

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pagination, pfquery, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I am updating my Parse app, after moving everything over to Heroku, using the open-sourced Parse servers.  My app has one section with a PFQueryTableViewController.  For a couple of years, I have had pagination disabled, as we only have about 50 items to be used in that table.  I ran it this morning, and at the bottom, after about 20 items, it pulled up the Load More option.  Here's the thing...it's still disabled.  Why is this pulling up?

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"FritchDirectory";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 0;

    }
    return self;
}
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    NSLog(@"QUERY");
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FritchDirectory"];
    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByAscending:@"title"];

    return query;
}

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.



// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    DirectoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DirectoryCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    }
    self.theObject = object;

    RSSEntryDirectory *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.theImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon@2x.png"];

    cell.theImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;



    PFFile *thumbnail = object[@"Picture"];


    if ([thumbnail isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

    }
    else {
    [thumbnail getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {

        UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        NSLog(@"%@", thumbnail);
            cell.theImageView.image = thumbnailImage;
        cell.theImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        NSLog(@"%@", thumbnailImage);
        //cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }];
    }





    cell.names.text = object[@"title"];
    NSLog(@"NAMES%@", object[@"title"]);
    CALayer * l = [cell.theImageView layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:11];
    [l setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    {
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:38];
        cell.names.font = cellFont;
        UIFont *cellFont2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:24];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = cellFont2;
    }
    else {
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:20];
        cell.names.font = cellFont;
        UIFont *cellFont2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:12];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = cellFont2;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What version of parse UI are you running ?

Comment: I am not sure.  The thing is, I've done NOTHING to the implementation file for this app, and it shows all entries on the existing version still, but this one loads up pagination issues.  Only thing I have done at all that COULD affect it is I changed app from a tab based app to a single view navigation controller.  Would that affect it?  @Cliffordwh

Comment: Even commenting out the `self.paginationEnabled` line and setting 1000 objects per page doesn't change the behavior at all.

Comment: It only loads the first 25, no matter what

Comment: Set a limit to that query and see if that resolves it ! [query setLimit:50];

Comment: @Cliffordwh That didn't change anything.  And I mean ANYTHING.  I even set the limit to 3, and it still loaded 25.  I'm thoroughly confused.  I added NSLogs to make sure that I was loading the right stuff, and they fire, so I'm in the right Class for sure.

Comment: Can you please share the complete file for me. Just edit your answer and paste the complete file in there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133479/discussion-between-cliffordwh-and-user717452).

Comment: @Cliffordwh I went back to the old style of having it inside of a Tab Bar Controller and it changed the query limit & everything. The View has its own ViewController and XIB file for it. In the old Tab Bar Controller, it was loaded in a NavigationController and I set the NIB name in properties. From the newer UI with just a NavigationController as root I call it by using:  `DirectoryViewController *dvController = [[DirectoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DirectoryViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear. `PFQueryTableViewController` doesn't work correctly when placed in the `NavigationViewController`.  Ensure that it lies in your `TableViewController`, `TabViewController`  or `ViewController`.